# message.member.roles.includes is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the discord bot to allow the command to be run only if the person has one of the roles in the array.

```
const validroles = ['owner', 'Co-Owner']

    if(!message.member.roles.includes(validroles)) {
      return message.channel.send(`**${message.author}, You do not have permission to use this command**`)
}
```

It gives me the error `TypeError: message.member.roles.includes is not a function`

How do I fix this?

Comment: It should be `message.member.roles.cache.includes` in v12

Comment: it still gives me an error

Comment: Is this the same error?

Comment: yes it is the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.member.roles` returns a [manager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) for the roles belonging to this member, so you need to use the `.cache` property to return the roles. `.cache` returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) that doesn't have an `.includes()` method. I think you were looking for the `.has()` property that checks if an element exists in the collection:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(validrole.id)) {
  return message.channel.send(`**${message.author}, You do not have permission to use this command**`)

}
```

Comment: for some reason, it just sends the message "You do not have permission to use this command" instead of running the command

Comment: I thought `validroles` was a role ID. Make sure you're passing the role's ID. Just updated my answer.

Comment: i have the role names in an array. should i be using role ids instead?

Comment: nvm i found a different solution